# gscoord and gspage or gspop cannot be used together in MediaWiki

Tags: java, mediawiki

I am trying to use wikipedia API- MediaWiki. I want to build a query which depending on the GPS coordinates, it can return me list of wikipedia pages.

However, I wanted to use a keyword to filter the results on combination with the coordinates.

In the wiki, there is the geoserach list that returns a list of pages near to a point.
This feature has parameters like gscoord, gspage. But I can not use them together.

Is there any idea of getting pages through a query depending on coordinates and a name, like natural park?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use one query as the input for another one. In the MediaWiki API that is called [“generators”](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Generator#Generators).

Here is a simple example, combining a `gscoord` query with a `gspage` query (using the former s input to the later. The query will show you pages geotagged within radius `10000` from coordinates `37.786971%7C-122.399677`, and within radius `100` from the page `Wikimedia Foundation`.

[`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=geosearch&ggsradius=10000&ggscoord=37.786971%7C-122.399677&list=geosearch&gsradius=100&gspage=Wikimedia%20Foundation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=geosearch&ggsradius=10000&ggscoord=37.786971%7C-122.399677&list=geosearch&gsradius=100&gspage=Wikimedia%20Foundation)

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, I want to create a list which are near to the given coordinates and filter them using a name, like museum, not the name of the page! I thought that gspage gives this option, but I can not. I want more a combination of geodata and srsearch. Do you have any idea of it?

Comment: I made a new question for that:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428893/can-i-make-a-query-using-geodata-from-mediawiki-for-getting-a-list-of-pages-de